# Screen pixelation issue with WebVew2 control in wpf

Tags: wpf, webview2

We are trying to migrate to webview2 control in WPF application. However, when I used the control as directed I came across this weird pixelation issue. I am attaching a screenshot of it. This happens after a few seconds when the screen remains idle and as soon as I move the mouse over it automatically corrects itself.

I have my control directly in a grid control [image]

Comment: Kindly note this webpage works perfectly fine when opened from browser directly

Comment: Just curious: Do you only see this on one website or is it general?

Comment: I forgot to mention everything works correctly when I run it locally, however, we do host our application in TerminalServer, and when I access this using remote login I see this flickering effect